# How to convert a List to RDD with scala and spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I'm trying to generate an `RDD` from a `List` and another `RDD` using `scala` and `spark`. The idea is to take a list of values, and generate an index containing all the entries of the original dataset that contains each value.
Here's the code that I'm trying

```
  def mcveInvertIndex(foos: List[String], bars: RDD[Int]): RDD[(String, Iterable[Int])] = {
    // filter function
    def hasVal(foo: String)(bar: Int): Boolean =
      foo.toInt == bar
    // call to sc.parallelize to ensure that an RDD is returned
    sc parallelize(
      foos map (_ match {
        case (s: String) => (s, bars filter hasVal(s))
      })
    )
  }
```

Unfortunately this does not compile in `sbt`

```
> compile
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to $TARGETDIR/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] $TARGETDIR/src/main/scala/wikipedia/WikipediaRanking.scala:56: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : List[(String, org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int])]
[error]  required: Seq[(String, Iterable[Int])]
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]       foos map (_ match {
[error]            ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Mar 11, 2017 7:11:31 PM
```

I really don't understand the errors that I'm getting. `List` is a subclass of `Seq`, and I presume that `RDD`s are a subclass of `Iterable`. Is there something obvious that I've missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution with for-comprehension (should use less memory than cartesian product)

```
  def mcveInvertIndex(foos: List[String],
                      bars: RDD[Int]): RDD[(String, Iterable[Int])] = 
  {

    // filter function
    def hasVal(foo: String, bar: Int): Boolean =
      foo.toInt == bar

    // Producing RDD[(String, Iterable[Int])]
    (for {
      bar <- bars // it's important to have RDD 
                  // at first position of for-comprehesion
                  // to produce the correct result type
      foo <- foos
      if hasVal(foo, bar)
    } yield (foo, bar)).groupByKey()
  }
```

Comment: It should be noted that you're solution closes over a local variable. So network overhead is going to be higher. Beware the dangers of closures in distributed work.

Comment: @JustinPihony, thanks for notice, so sould it be `aggregateByKey(Iterable.empty[Int])((is, i) => i :: is.toList, _ ++ _)` instead of `groupByKey` to avoid network overhead?

Comment: It's less groupByKey and more the use of foos within the RDD

Comment: Ok, undestand, how big will be overhead if length of `foos` limited let say on 100? So does it means that `foos` should be sent to each node one time or something more? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, RDD is not an Iterable, so you have to combine the two in some way and then aggregate them. This is my quick solution, although there might be a more efficient way:

```
def mcveInvertIndex(foos: List[String], bars: RDD[Int]): RDD[(String, Iterable[Int])] = {
    sc.makeRDD(foos)
      .cartesian(bars)
      .keyBy(x=>x._1)
      .aggregateByKey(Iterable.empty[Int])(
        (agg: Iterable[Int], currVal: (String, Int))=>{
          if(currVal._1.toInt != currVal._2) agg
          else currVal._2 +: agg.toList
        }, 
        _ ++ _ 
     )
  }
```